# message implode() invalid arguments passed in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

when I tried to save my data then every image is saved in a new row. I want to save all image urls in the same column by implode function but it doesn't work.here is my code.
My Model where i got $post_image as an array

```
public function create_post($post_image){
                    $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'));
                    $image = implode(',',(array)$post_image);    
        $data = array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'slug' => $slug,
            'body' => $this->input->post('body'),
            'category_id' => $this->input->post('category_id'),
            'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
            'post_image' => $image
        );

        return $this->db->insert('posts', $data);
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or is it not outputting the correct results. Please post the structure of $post_image array and the output of $image.

Comment: Store a data group in a field is against the normalization of a database. You should have a table `images` (you can set a name, an url, a tooltip, etc.) and an intermediary table `posts_images` which stores the id of your image and the id of your post. See more [Unnormalized from - Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unnormalized_form).

Comment: see the resultin database  here
https://imagebin.ca/v/3y6a89pHvV2o
where i want  tostore all images in same row

Comment: its very simple, u r not passing array to implode()  that is why this error come, check you $post_image variable

Comment: So what is the content of `$post_image`? It may not be an array, so you have to check the type with `is_array($post_image)` before doint your `implode()`.

Comment: my function like followng
public function create_post($post_image){
                        $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'));
                        $image = implode(',',$post_image);
                        
   $data = array(
    'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
    'slug' => $slug,
    'body' => $this->input->post('body'),
    'category_id' => $this->input->post('category_id'),
    'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
    'post_image' => $image
   );
   return $this->db->insert('posts', $data);
  }
but in database it Array,Array,Array for pic

Comment: Actually i am new one in php, codeigniter so please solve my issue.